# SharePoint 2013 Online - REST crosssite upload to - SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite) 403 - Forbidden

Tags: jquery, json, rest, sharepoint-2013, http-status-code-403

What am I doing wrong here? I am able to upload to the same site collection without SP.AppContextSite code and changing both URLs.  All HTML Markup and jquery is being embedded into a page on /sites/dev.  Target library is /test/Documents. I have full permissions on both site collections.

```
  function ProcessUpload(fileInput) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (result) {
        var fileName = '',
         libraryName = '',
         fileData = '';

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(result.target.result)
        for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
            fileData += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i])
        }

        // once we have the file perform the actual upload
        PerformUpload(fileInput.name, fileData);

    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput);
}

function PerformUpload(fileName, fileData) {
    var url;



        url = 'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev' +
        "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='false')?"+
          "@TargetSite='" + 'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test'+ "'" +
            "&@TargetLibrary='Documents'" +
            "&@TargetFileName='CV" + fileName + "'";
            alert(url);


    // use the request executor (cross domain library) to perform the upload

$.ajax({     
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()

        },
        data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'Title': 'New title' }),


        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        binaryStringRequestBody: true,
        body: fileData,
        success:successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and add encodeURIComponent() on all uri parameter values. This ensures they are read properly on the server.

```
url = 'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev' + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='false')?"+
      "@TargetSite='" + encodeURIComponent('https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test')+ "'" +
      "&@TargetLibrary='Documents'" +
      "&@TargetFileName='CV" + encodeURIComponent(fileName) + "'";
```

Comment: Assuming ofcourse you are using a browser that supports the FileReader http://caniuse.com/filereader

Answer (score 0):

try change your url string from url = 'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev' +  TO  _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +,
also, use executeAsync.

$.getScript(hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", PerformUpload(fileName, fileData));

function PerformUpload(fileName, fileData) {
    var url;

```
    url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +        "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='false')?"+
      "@TargetSite='" + 'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test'+ "'" +
        "&@TargetLibrary='Documents'" +
        "&@TargetFileName='CV" + fileName + "'";
        alert(url);

    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
       executor.executeAsync(
            {
          url: url,
```

method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()

```
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'Title': 'New title' }),


    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    binaryStringRequestBody: true,
    body: fileData,
    success:successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
```

}

Comment: Please edit the code block in your answer to have proper format and indentation.